# Load vectors into gensim Word2Vec model - not KeyedVectors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I'm attempting to load some pre-trained vectors into a gensim `Word2Vec` model, so they can be retrained with new data. My understanding is I can do the retraining with `gensim.Word2Vec.train()`. However, the only way I can find to load the vectors is with `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path/to/file.bin', binary=True)` which creates an object of what is usually the `wv` attribute of a `gensim.Word2Vec` model. But this object, on it's own, does not have a `train()` method, which is what I need to retrain the vectors.

So how do I get these vectors into an actual `gensim.Word2Vec` model?

Answer (score 1):

[`Word2Vec.load`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load) is not deprecated, so you can use it, assuming that your pre-trained model has been saved with [`Word2Vec.save`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.save).

```py
# Train and save the model
model = Word2Vec(size=100, window=4, min_count=5, workers=4)
model.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=50)
model.save('word-vectors.bin')

...

# Later in another script: load and continue training
model = Word2Vec.load('word-vectors.bin')
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=50)
```